# Deep copy of CMSampleBufferRef

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, video-processing, core-video

I'm trying to perform a deep copy of a CMSampleBufferRef for audio and video connection ? I need to use this buffer for delayed processing. Can somebody helper here by point to a sample code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem

I needs access to the sample data for a long period of time.

try many way:

`CVPixelBufferRetain`  -----> program broken
`CVPixelBufferPool`    -----> program broken
`CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes` ----> it can solve this program,but this  will reduce performance,Apple is not recommended to do so

`CMSampleBufferCreateCopy` --->it is ok, and apple recommended it.

List : To maintain optimal performance, some sample buffers directly reference pools of memory that may need to be reused by the device system and other capture inputs. This is frequently the case for uncompressed device native capture where memory blocks are copied as little as possible. If multiple sample buffers reference such pools of memory for too long, inputs will no longer be able to copy new samples into memory and those samples will be dropped. If your application is causing samples to be dropped by retaining the provided CMSampleBuffer objects for too long, but it needs access to the sample data for a long period of time, consider copying the data into a new buffer and then calling CFRelease on the sample buffer (if it was previously retained) so that the memory it references can be reused.

REF:https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturefileoutputdelegate/1390096-captureoutput

that might be what you need:

## pragma mark -captureOutput

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{
    if (connection == m_videoConnection) {        
        /* if you did not read m_sampleBuffer ,here you must CFRelease m_sampleBuffer, it is causing samples to be dropped 
        */
        if (m_sampleBuffer) {
            CFRelease(m_sampleBuffer);
            m_sampleBuffer = nil;
        }

        OSStatus status = CMSampleBufferCreateCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer, &m_sampleBuffer);
        if (noErr != status) {
            m_sampleBuffer = nil;
        }
        NSLog(@"m_sampleBuffer = %p sampleBuffer= %p",m_sampleBuffer,sampleBuffer);
    }
}
```

## pragma mark -get CVPixelBufferRef to use  for a long period of time

```
- (ACResult) readVideoFrame: (CVPixelBufferRef *)pixelBuffer{
    while (1) {
        dispatch_sync(m_readVideoData, ^{
            if (!m_sampleBuffer) {
                _readDataSuccess = NO;
                return;
            }

            CMSampleBufferRef sampleBufferCopy = nil;
            OSStatus status = CMSampleBufferCreateCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, m_sampleBuffer, &sampleBufferCopy);
            if ( noErr == status)
            {
                 CVPixelBufferRef buffer  = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBufferCopy);

                 *pixelBuffer = buffer;

                 _readDataSuccess = YES;

                 NSLog(@"m_sampleBuffer = %p ",m_sampleBuffer);

                 CFRelease(m_sampleBuffer);
                 m_sampleBuffer = nil;

             }
             else{
                 _readDataSuccess = NO;
                 CFRelease(m_sampleBuffer);
                 m_sampleBuffer = nil;
             }
        });

        if (_readDataSuccess) {
            _readDataSuccess = NO;
            return ACResultNoErr;
        }
        else{
            usleep(15*1000);
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

then you can use it such this:

```
-(void)getCaptureVideoDataToEncode{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(){
        while (1) {
            CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;
            ACResult result= [videoCapture readVideoFrame:&buffer];
            if (ACResultNoErr == result) {
                ACResult error = [videoEncode encoder:buffer outputPacket:&streamPacket];
                if (buffer) {
                    CVPixelBufferRelease(buffer);
                    buffer = NULL;
                }
                if (ACResultNoErr == error) {
                NSLog(@"encode success");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: do I need the infinite loop if I want just get current stream buffer and analyze it every second?

Comment: This won't work. You are simply retaining the original reference for 1 iteration and then releasing it on the next.

Comment: I tried CMSampleBufferCreateCopy() and it indeed fixed my problem the same as yours. But according to Apple's document about CMSampleBufferCreateCopy()(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/1489543-cmsamplebuffercreatecopy?language=objc): "The copy is shallow: scalar properties (sizes and timing) are copied directly, the data buffer and format description are retained, and the attachments that can be propagated are retained by the copy's dictionary. If sbuf's data is not ready, the copy will be set to track its readiness."  So why it works? Could anyone get an explaination?

Comment: No, not really: There was still some times that CMSampleBufferCreateCopy() did not fix the dropping input samples problem. So I think it still needs a real deep copy.

Answer (score -3):

I do this. `CMSampleBufferCreateCopy` can indeed  deep copy
but a new problem is appear
`captureOutput` delegate doesn't work